# Insert range using IF formula in SUMIF function with multiple criteria (using arrayformula)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I used an `arrayformula` with my `sumif` function which has several criteria and ranges to expand automatically across a set column (B). The formula below works perfectly:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('DATA'!$N:$N&'DATA'!$U:$U&'DATA'!$V:$V&'SFDC DATA'!$BV:$BV,$B$6:$B&$E$30&$D$26&$C$36,'DATA'!$AG:$AG)`.

I want to make it more dynamic and insert an `IF` statement to actually refer to a range vs another one based on certain conditions. For ex: `IF($A$6:$A=XX,'DATA'!$N:$N,'DATA'!$M:$M)`.

The formula then breaks if I do this `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF($A$6:$A=XX,'DATA'!$N:$N,'DATA'!$M:$M)&'DATA'!$U:$U&'DATA'!$V:$V&'SFDC DATA'!$BV:$BV,$B$6:$B&$E$30&$D$26&$C$36,'DATA'!$AG:$AG)`.

Any way to make it work?

Comment: Welcome. Please share a link to a test sheet.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916456/insert-range-using-if-formula-in-sumif-function-with-multiple-criteria-using-ar).